# Make Polymer paper-tabs to be centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, components

Is it even possible to make polymer paper-tabs with "scrollable" set to true to be horizontally centered in a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well anything is possible. :) Two things you need to do basically.

First, make your *paper-tabs* `text-align: center`.

```
  #scrollableTabs {
      text-align: center;
  }
```

Then, 'cause the `scrollable` attribute adds an `absolute` position to the `#tabsContent` *div*, you need to overwrite this by giving it a default value of `static`.

```
  #scrollableTabs #tabsContent {
      position: static;
  }
```

That's all! See it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/41b8a7jmuFnigsOAOUad?p=preview).

Comment: wow, thanks. Your example is exactly what I'm looking for. I tried to apply the style but only the one for `#scrollableTabs` was applied. The one for `#scrollableTabs #tabsContent` wasn't. When I inspected it in the dev tool, I don't see the style at all. It works when I changed the position manually in the dev tool. It seems like my style didn't penetrate deep enough. Do you have an idea why that might be?

Comment: It could be that your style has <style is="custom-style"> which prevents the css from leaking down.

Comment: You're right. I had it as `custom-style`. However, even after I deleted that, I still don't see the style being applied, or even listed in dev tools.

Comment: Try clearing the cache maybe? Also try putting your code in a plunker so I can have a look.

Comment: This is my code reduced to what's relevant and sufficient for this case http://plnkr.co/edit/DpWqQ2MVfo0wxOhJiHws?p=preview

Comment: Inside the css, it's `#tabsContent`, not `#tabsContainer`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88325/discussion-between-vleong-and-justin-xl).